# Present child view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController subclass that shows images. This view controller is inside a larger view controller that has other content. I want to be able to tap on an image in the page view controller and have that page view controller removed from where it is and presented full screen, where additional controls such as zooming and panning around the image would be available. Then, I also need a way to be able to dismiss it from being presented full screen and to re-insert it in the original parent view controller.

```objectivec
- (void)handleTapGesture {
    UIViewController *parentViewController = self.parentViewController;

    [self didMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self removeFromParentViewController];

    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [parentViewController presentViewController:self animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But when I do this, I can see the dimming view and everything that is set up automatically when presenting the view controller, but the view controller itself is not visible.

I viewed it in the view debugger, but it looks like the frame of the page view controller is zero sized. Here is some output from the debugger:

> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <MyPageViewController: 0x10ca8f000>.
>
> Printing description of $21:
>
> <_UIPageViewControllerContentView: 0x117b04c40; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x283491be0>>

I am not sure why that is though and I do not know how to debug this since I am not specifying any layout explicitly. From what I understand, when I present this view controller, I should not have to specify any constraints or sizes as that is to be handled by the view controller transition. All I am doing is trying to make a view controller, that was a child view controller, be presented modally full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view containment calls are incorrect. (See below.)

But the “Unbalanced calls” error message suggests that there might be some other, deeper problem elsewhere in your code base. The incorrect view controller containment calls are insufficient to manifest this error.

One generally gets this error when attempting to initiate a transition while another is underway (e.g., trying to present/dismiss view controllers inside the `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` or `viewWillDisappear` methods).

But the supplied code snippet is insufficient to manifest the problem you describe. We need [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I would suggest you create a blank project and figure out what you need to add to it in order to manifest your error.

---

That having been said, the correct view controller containment calls to remove a child are `willMoveToParentViewController`, followed by `removeFromSuperview`, followed by `removeFromParentViewController`, e.g.:

```objectivec
[self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self removeFromParentViewController];
```

Note, I did not call `didMoveToParentViewController`, because, as [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621405-didmovetoparentviewcontroller?language=objc) says:

> The `removeFromParentViewController` method automatically calls the `didMoveToParentViewController:` method of the child view controller after it removes the child.

---

Obviously, when adding a child, the converse is true, that you do not call `willMoveToParentViewController`, but you do call `didMoveToParentViewController`:

```objectivec
[self addChildViewController:child];
[self.view addSubview:child.view];
child.view.frame = ...;
[self didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Again, the documentation advises us:

> When your custom container calls the `addChildViewController:` method, it automatically calls the `willMoveToParentViewController:` method of the view controller to be added as a child before adding it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I did update the call sequence as you suggested, but as you mentioned, it did not really help the issue with the view being zero sized. I will try to come up with a more complete test that I can post. But in the meantime, is this even the right way to take a child view controller and present that instance full screen? I have tried looking up examples of how to do this, but I can't seem to find anything. Basically I want something like the Apple Photos app where when an image is selected, it is shown full screen and the spot where it was previously is now empty.

Comment: @ashipma - I personally would not remove the view from the page view controller’s view. I would recommend just presenting a new instance. You really don't want to be reaching into another view controller, removing one of its views, just because you want to present something.